# Given the probability of several independent events, how does one show one of the event's probabilities?

Tags: probability

The problem reads, "Say that $C_1, C_2, \ldots ,C_k$ are independent events that have respective probabilities $p_1, p_2, \ldots , p_k$.  Argue that the probability of at least one of $C_1, C_2, \ldots ,C_k$ is equal to $1-(1-p_1)(1-p_2)\ldots (1-p_k)$."

Say we flip a coin twice, let $C_1$ be the event where the first flip results in heads, and $C_2$ be the event where the second flip results in heads.  Then $P(C_1)=P(C_2)=\frac{1}{2} \neq 1-(1-\frac{1}{2})(1-\frac{1}{2}) = \frac{3}{4}$.

What am I missing?

I see that $P((C_1 \cup C_2 \cup ... \cup C_k)^C)=1-(p_1 + p_2 + ... + p_k - p_1p_2...p_k)=(1-p_1)(1-p_2)...(1-p_k)=P(C_1^C \cap C_2^C \cap ... \cap C_k^C)$, but I don't see how this helps.

Comment: I really don't understand your question.  Is there a contradiction somewhere, such as  two different numerical values for the same quantity?  If so, what is it, precisely?

Comment: It seems to me that $C_1$ and $C_2$ from my example are independent and each has probability $\frac{1}{2}$, but neither has the probability that the problem claims it should.  Isn't the problem claiming that one of the probabilities should be $\frac{3}{4}$?

Comment: It's saying that $P(C_1\cup C_2)=3/4$, because of all that stuff.  In 2 fair flips the outcomes can be HH, HT, TH, or TT.  In the first 3 cases you get at least 1 head; in the last case you get 0 heads.  So here the right answer is clearly $3/4$.

Comment: So maybe I don't understand the question, either.  I read the problem statement as saying that $P(C_i)$ equals the quantity for at least one $i$.  Are you reading the problem statement as saying $P(\cup_{a \in A}C_a)$ equals the quantity for some $A \subset \{1,2,...,k\}$?  If this is the case, wouldn't $A=\{1,2,...,k\}$ work regardless of the events and the probabilities?

Comment: The problem lies in your interpretation of the story problem into formulas.  Usually when we ask for "chance that at least one of   A and B occur" we  mean $P(A\cup B)$ and not "one of the values $P(A)$ or $P(B)$".